# How can I dynamically get all my facebook app ids

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created 4 apps in facebook. In [Facebook apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) I can see all my apps and the IDs. But I will get all my app ids dynamically/programmatically. When I type in graph explorer "me/accounts" I get the id of only one app. How can I dynamically get ids of all my apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [March 2013 Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> **Removing apps from /me/accounts/**
>
> We will no longer show apps under /me/accounts/ in the Graph API. You can access the list of apps a user is a developer on by hitting /me/applications/developer/.

The one result that you are getting is not an app, but could be app page/community

Comment: Thanks Shadowfax it works! Is there any manual about working with apps dinamically?

Comment: I dont want to fetch the apps of a user. I want to fetch only my apps. And need that because each app must be created dynamacally for different domains. I have written a website template which developers can take and create websites. On each of this websites I want to integrate facebook's functionality. And beacause the domains are different, apps must have also different configurations: domain, canvas url... Of course developers can also create the apps manulaly, but this is a too much work.

Comment: ... Thats why I need to bild my template, so that it can create and configure apps dynamically for each domain. And unfortunately I can not find any manual/tutorial about that.

Comment: I hav got one more question. Can I get also the secret keys?

Comment: You mean `App Secret Key`? Its in the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) page

Comment: Yes I know. I mean I want to get that also dynamically. Not from Dashboard.

Comment: You cant, both appId and appSecret, you have to explicitly write in your code.

Comment: then why do we need setAppId and setApiSecret functions?